# Replacing 8 AA batteries with 3 186500 batteries

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, replacement

My old R/C toy car, can be powered with 8 1.5V AA batteries or 8 1.2V Ni-Cad Batteries. Currently I try to use 3 186500 Li-Ion batteries instead. I planned to use a charger- and protection module TC4056a and a LM2596 buck converter. Now I am unsure about the voltage I should set on the buck converter.

Because: 
8 * 1.5V = 12V (for regular AA batteries)
and 
8 * 1.2V = 9.6V (for Ni-Cad batteries)

Or can I assume there is already a converter built-in, since the device can be powered with 9.6V or 12V?

Comment: `Now I am unsure about the voltage I should set on the buck converter.` what buck converter?

Comment: I planned on using a LM2596 buck converter and a TC4056a Li-Ion charger and protection module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or can I assume there is already a converter built-in

For the electronic stuff (RF, MCU etc) there should be a regulator inside (5V, 3V3 or even maybe 1V8). Without knowing the details we can't say if the regulator(s) is/are switching or linear. But for the mechanical stuff probably the supply voltage is used directly (i.e. without any regulator/conversion). So, higher voltage might increase the stress and temperature of the motors whilst a lower voltage brings a reduced performance.

An 18650 battery has a nominal voltage of 3.6~3.7 VDC, a maximum of 4.2 VDC (when fully charged), and a minimum (depleted) voltage of 2~3 VDC (depending on whether there's a CHG/DISCHG protection device inside e.g. DW001). So, 3 of them in series will bring a bank voltage of 12.6 VDC at max, and a minimum of up to 9 VDC when depleted.

> I planned to use a charger- and protection module TC4056a and a LM2596 buck converter.

Make sure the load is disconnected from the battery (i.e. remove the battery from the toy or switch the toy off) during recharging. Or else the charger will try to supply the load/car as well which will bring charging problems (the output current that the charger regulates will partly be used by the battery).

> Now I am unsure about the voltage I should set on the buck converter.

You have a verified working voltage range already: 9.6~12 VDC. The lower bound of this range is equal to the nominal voltage of 18650 bank. Since the toy can work with 8 of Ni-Cd batteries, if we assume that the depleted voltage of a Ni-Cd cell is 0.9~1.0 VDC then we can assume that the toy can work with voltages down to 8.8 VDC.

So a good compromise for the toy could be `9 VDC`. But there are a few problems here:

- The power of the motors will probably be reduced with this voltage so you may not be happy with the performance.
- The 2596 buck regulator requires an input-output difference (i.e. dropout) of ~1 VDC (at least). So if you set the buck's output to 9 VDC the battery will be used until its discharge voltage reaches ~10 VDC which can be higher than the nominal voltage. This means a reduced utilisation of the battery.

So my recommendation here is to use

- a buck-boost regulator with an output voltage of 12 VDC,
- or a boost regulator with an output voltage of 12 VDC, but the 18650 batteries (input to the regulator) should be in parallel instead (3~4.2 VDC) -- The 4056 charger can't guarantee a balanced recharging when the batteries are in parallel, though.

With the two options above the battery usage can be maximised whilst maintaining an acceptable performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very very helpful!

Comment: Batteries in parallel are self balancing. Which will lead to exiting moments in the form if smoke and flames if they aren't balanced beforehand. Preferably discharged.